# How do I access an array with objects?

Tags: php

I am trying to learn how to access objects in an array. For example how do I access the name? [name] => Yearly Membership.

```
Array
(
    [0] => WC_Memberships_User_Membership Object
        (
            [id] => 56325
            [plan_id] => 55119
            [plan] => WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan Object
                (
                    [id] => 55119
                    [name] => Yearly Membership
                    [slug] => yearly-membership
                    [post] => WP_Post Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 55119
                            [post_author] => 4
                            [post_date] => 2016-12-01 00:18:27
                            [post_date_gmt] => 2016-12-01 00:18:27
                            [post_content] => 
                            [post_title] => Yearly Membership
                            [post_excerpt] => 
                            [post_status] => publish
                            [comment_status] => closed
                            [ping_status] => closed
                            [post_password] => 
                            [post_name] => yearly-membership
                            [to_ping] => 
                            [pinged] => 
                            [post_modified] => 2017-09-20 01:16:15
                            [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-09-20 01:16:15
                            [post_content_filtered] => 
                            [post_parent] => 0
                            [guid] => https://sharpescout.bdanzer.com/?post_type=wc_membership_plan&p=55119
                            [menu_order] => 0
                            [post_type] => wc_membership_plan
                            [post_mime_type] => 
                            [comment_count] => 0
                            [filter] => raw
                        )

                    [access_method_meta:protected] => _access_method
                    [default_access_method:protected] => unlimited
                    [access_length_meta:protected] => _access_length
                    [access_start_date_meta:protected] => _access_start_date
                    [access_end_date_meta:protected] => _access_end_date
                    [product_ids_meta:protected] => _product_ids
                    [members_area_meta:protected] => _members_area_sections
                    [email_content_meta:protected] => _email_content
                    [rules:WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [user_id] => 317
            [status] => wcm-active
            [post] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 56325
                    [post_author] => 317
                    [post_date] => 2017-09-19 04:21:38
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-09-19 04:21:38
                    [post_content] => 
                    [post_title] => Auto Draft
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => wcm-active
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => um_59c09b4d1c87e
                    [post_name] => auto-draft-9
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_modified] => 2017-09-19 04:21:38
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-09-19 04:21:38
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 55119
                    [guid] => https://sharpescout.bdanzer.com/?post_type=wc_user_membership&p=56325
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => wc_user_membership
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

            [product:WC_Memberships_User_Membership:private] => 
            [type:protected] => manually-assigned
            [start_date_meta:protected] => _start_date
            [end_date_meta:protected] => _end_date
            [cancelled_date_meta:protected] => _cancelled_date
            [paused_date_meta:protected] => _paused_date
            [paused_intervals_meta:protected] => _paused_intervals
            [product_id_meta:protected] => _product_id
            [order_id_meta:protected] => _order_id
            [previous_owners_meta:protected] => _previous_owners
            [renewal_login_token_meta] => _renewal_login_token
        )

)
```

The function I am using is called: wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships(); and I set in my code:

```
$get_user_membership = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships();
```

I tried to echo out even just the id

```
echo $get_user_membership[0]->[id];
```

But I get an error so I know I am doing something wrong.

How can I access each of these values in this? Any help would be very helpful

edit:
here is the error I got in the example of trying to get id

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in (removed filename) on line 325
```

Comment: Read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and don't quit until you reach the section [*"Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing). And read about [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). The syntax `->[]` is an invalid combination of the two concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by running around array `[]` and object `{}` so:

```
var_dump($get_user_membership[0]->{'plan'}->{'name'});
```

Comment: Thanks! That did end up working for me when I did: echo $get_user_membership[0]->{'plan'}->{'name'}; . Is there other methods of accessing the same thing or is this the best solution?

Comment: `$get_user_membership[0]->{'plan'}->{'name'}` is just a complicated way to write `$get_user_membership[0]->plan->name`. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @axiac The question was *How can I access each of these values in this?* and the answerer has provided a solution therefore I'd argue that it is in fact a valid answer, whether it is done in a verbose way or not is not an issue.

Comment: @bdanzer Hi is the simple way to known how without any loop, thinking on how to get and run around object array multidimensional. Now you can implement a simple loop to the other value.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
var_dump($get_user_membership[0]->plan->name);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well too, and is a lot cleaner than the other answer given. I appreciate it. Is this the best solution? Or would there be better ways to access the data?

Comment: Please stay on topic, answers should not be used to query or question.

Comment: @bdanzer I'd use curly brackets for accessing an object's properties these ways: `$obj->{$variable}`; `$obj->{"key_$variable"}`; `$obj->{'space inproperty'}`. otherwise I like to keep it simple `$obj->property`